# Does a nonconstant holomorphic function always map the unit disk into the interior of $(\Gamma)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find a counterexample disproving the following statement: If $f$ is nonconstant and holomorphic on an open domain $A$ with $\overline{\mathbb{D}} \subset A \subset \mathbb{C}$ (where $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk), then $$f(\mathbb{D})=Int(\Gamma),$$ where $tr(\Gamma)=f(\partial \mathbb{D})$ is the trace and $Int(\Gamma)=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\backslash tr(\Gamma) : n(z,\Gamma)\neq 0\}$ is the interior of the curve $\Gamma$.

I have already tried several types of functions, among others moebius transformations like $f: z \mapsto \frac{0.5-z}{1-0.5z}$ but all of them seem to map $\partial \mathbb{D}$ to itself and $\mathbb{D}$ to itself, so that they cannot provide a counterexample: The interior of $f(\partial \mathbb{D})$ is just $\mathbb{D}$. Polynomials do not work either, as they map $\partial \mathbb{D}$ to just another circle whose interior is the image of $\mathbb{D}$.

If someone could provide a tiny hint on what to look at here, e.g. which types of functions, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.  Why do you say polynomials do not work?  For the polynomial $(z+1)^{10}$ the image of the unit circle is

[image]

Perhaps you can make polynomials that produce still more complicated curves.